# calling a sub function with a button in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have 10  Sub function macros in "This workbook". Instead of running each macros, everytime i wanted an userform with button, and when I click , it should execute all the Sub function in "This workbook".

I created another function like calling, and I used the following code,

```
Sub calling()


Call lookup
Call RangeTest
 Call datecompare
Call AutoPivot
Call Autochart
 Call pivot
Call chart
Call pivot1
End Sub
```

so, whenever I go for macros, I select Sub calling() and it executes the 10 Sub functions. I would like to have it through a button click. Could anyone suggest how I can do this ?

Comment: Attach a button to `Sub calling()`? What prevents you from dong that?

Comment: you mean , creating a button in a sheet and then assigning macro Sub calling to the button ?

Comment: Yes, buttons can be placed directly in sheets and you already seem to know how to use buttons on userforms. There isn't all that much difference.

Comment: but i get an error expected function or variable

Comment: So your sub `calling` has a bug?

Comment: Ya.´Sub calling has an bug

Comment: You might need something like e.g. `Call ThisWorkbook.chart` but 1) Subs should typically be in general code modules rather than `ThisWorkbook` (which is typically reserved for event handlers) and 2) using names like `chart` for subs which potentially clash with Excel VBA names (`Chart` is a built-in type) is poor design.

Comment: it works :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should simply add a button from the developper ribbon and assign it to calling().
However, make sure all your macros are in the same module or else you'll have to specify it. If you still get an error it would be interesting to see on what line the error is coming from.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the confusion arises because you are trying to use an ActiveX button. If you were using a Form Button, the macro name would appear in the "Assign Macro" popup box. But the ActiveX version doesn't provide the dialog, and because the button exists on the page, doesn't easily see the macros from "This Workbook".

Here's what worked for me.

Within Sheet3:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Application.Run ("'ThisWorkbook.calling'")
End Sub
```